# Upstart: Run service as unprivileged user and pre-start script as root

Tags: linux, upstart

I have following upstart job:

```
description "posty api"


start on mysql
stop on shutdown

env RACK_ENV=production

setuid vmail
setgid vmail

chdir /opt/posty_api

pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/run/posty
    chown -R vmail:root /var/run/posty
end script

exec /usr/local/bin/unicorn -D -c /opt/posty_api/unicorn.rb --env production >> /var/log/posty/upstart.log 2>&1

post-stop exec kill `cat /var/run/posty/unicorn.pid`

respawn
respawn limit 1 10
```

To create the folder in `/var/run` I need root privileges. How can I run some parts of the upstart job as root, and the service itself as unprivileged user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`upstart` has no facility equivalent to `systemd`'s `PermissionsStartOnly` setting.  All processes in the job run as the user set via [the `setuid` stanza](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#setuid), as the Cookbook says.

So do things the daemontools way.

Use [`setuidgid`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/setuidgid.html), [`setuidgid`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/setuidgid.8.html), [`s6-setuidgid`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-setuidgid.html), [`chpst`](http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html), [`runuid`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=runuid.8), or [`setuidgid`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/setuidgid.html) in the `exec` stanza:

```
exec \
setuidgid somebody \
unicorn -D -c /opt/posty_api/unicorn.rb --env production >> /var/log/posty/upstart.log 2>&1
```

That's a terrible logging mechanism, by the way.  The daemontools way would have a proper, automatically cycled, rotateable-on-demand, size-capped, log using [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html), [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html), [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html), [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html), [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8), or [`cyclog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/cyclog.html).  `upstart` is tricky to integrate with those, however, [given its `expect` mechanism](https://serverfault.com/questions/114052/).

```
expect fork
exec \
setuidgid somebody \
unicorn -D -c /opt/posty_api/unicorn.rb --env production 2>&1 | \
/usr/local/bin/chdir /var/log/ \
setuidgid log \
cyclog posty/unicorn/
```

(The `chdir` here is the chain-loading one from the `nosh` package, and isn't strictly necessary.  But it makes things somewhat tidier.)

Comment: Thx for the explanation and the hint for logging. I created already two upstartjobs, the prepare job referencing with `start on starting posty`. But the logging is way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setguid in script block and it will affect only given block. Something like this:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/kafka.conf
description "kafka broker"

limit nofile 32768 32768

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on [!2345]

respawn
respawn limit 2 5

umask 007

kill timeout 300

pre-start script
    # here you are root
    ls -alh /root/
end script

chdir /usr/local/lib/kafka

script
    setuid kafka
    setgid kafka
    # here you are user/group kafka
    /usr/local/lib/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /usr/local/lib/kafka/config/server.properties
end script
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The script section does not execute.

Comment: This results in a `setuid: not found` error.